# replace substring of a string using dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to know how to find and change substring of a string using dictionary in swift.

```
var string = "I like doggo doggo and cat"
let dic = ["doggo" : "dog", "cat" : "kitten"]
```

result string would be "I like dog dog and kitten"

How to find all matching keys in string and change with values of dictionary ?

I will store hundreds or thousands of words in dictionary. It doesn't have to be dictionary. I just want to find a word and replace it.

Thanks

Comment: Are the substrings always full words?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to enumerate the dictionary and replace all occurrences of the key with the value respectively

```
var string = "I like doggo doggo and cat"
let dic = ["doggo" : "dog", "cat" : "kitten"]
for (key, value) in dic {
    string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: key, with: value)
}
print(string)
```

To consider only whole words wrap the key in the regex word boundaries specifier (`\b`) and add the `.regularExpression` option

```
var string = "I like doggo doggo and cat"
let dic = ["doggo" : "dog", "kit" : "package", "cat" : "kitten"]
for (key, value) in dic {
    string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b" + key + "\\b", with: value, options: .regularExpression)
}
print(string)
```

Comment: This will have undefined behavior when the dictionary contains keys or values that are prefixes of other keys. Consider what would happen if you added `"kit": "package"`. If the dictionary happens to be order with with `"cat": "kitten"` first, then `"kit": "package"`, you'll end up with `"I like dog dog and packageten"`

Comment: @Alexander Good point, please see the update

Comment: I think that would still be an issue with `"cat": "kitten", "kitten": "kittens"`. The result will sometimes have plural kittens, sometimes not, depending on the dictionary's arbitrary ordering